# Cannot find an AD group with a bracket/brace in the name

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a Domain local group in my AD called *Officer (Level 3 Ref_9999999*

I am trying to find it with this command.

$Job=Get-ADGRoup -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountNAme = OFFICER (LEVEL 3 Ref_999999)"

Unfortunatley the ( parenthesis in the group name is fouling the command and I don't know how to handle it?

I've tried enclosing it in quotes, double quotes.

Can anyone help a newbie?

Answer (score 0):

LDAP filters are not PowerShell - they have their own syntax rules.  There should be no spaces around the '=' sign.

Also, you haven't closed the parentheses around the search term:

```
$Job = Get-ADGRoup -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountNAme=OFFICER (LEVEL 3 Ref_999999))"
```